# Problem running a Docker container for RFID-RC522 on an Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi4, pi, mfrc522

I got an error when I try to run a running a Docker container for RFID-RC522 on a Raspberry Pi 4. Test program is written in Phyton, and I can't figure out what the problem is

**This is my configuration and testfiles: **

Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit).
Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243
RFID-RC522 from Arduino.

**Python test program:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()
try:
        id, text = reader.read()
        print(id)
        print(text)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
#FROM python:3.8-alpine
FROM python:3.8-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y
RUN pip install smbus2
RUN pip install spidev
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir rpi.gpio
RUN pip install mfrc522
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "Read.py"]
```

**Build Container:**
sudo docker build -t read-rfid-python-app .

**Run Container:**
docker run -it read-rfid-python-app

**And the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Read.py", line 6, in <module>
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.READER = MFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mfrc522/MFRC522.py", line 130, in __init__
    self.spi.open(bus, device)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Have I missed installing something in the Dockerfile? Everything works as intended outside of Docker.

The problem is very similar to 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873696/unable-to-connect-rc522-rfid-module-to-raspberry-pi-4'. With that difference is that it is only when it is placed in a container that the problem occurs. Does something need to be done about SPI?

Thanks in advance!

Br

Mark Stone

Comment: As your container is build to isolate processes from the host, everything inside the container does not have access by default to e.g. the spi bus. You need to find out how to "mount" the spi bus into your container

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply tjarbo! First I tried adding 'RUN pip3 install RPI.GPIO' but
the problem turned out to be that I needed to add 'docker run --privileged ... '. So in my case RPI.GPIO was not needed. Once again Thank you.

Comment: I guess it should be possible to find a solution other than running in Privileged mode. Does anyone have a suggestion?